# Duplica registro

Tags: c#

Estoy leyendo archivos excel, y tengo un problema alguno archivos se muestran asi...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tienen dos espacios, y yo tengo un `else` con una function...

```
else if (data[0] == "")
{
 listinformation.Add(information);
 info.DATA = list.ToArray();                 
 string result = client.SaveInformation(information);
 list.Clear();
}
```

Para guardar la información busco por palabra no hay ningún problema en eso, el problema esta cuando llega a la posición donde estan estos espacios en blanco, entonces entra al `else`  y va a la `function` `SaveInformaction` y hace el guardado correctamente, regresa y vuelve a entrar de nuevo al `else`, guardándolo de nuevo, cuando ya se había registrado...
como le puedo hacer para quitar esos espacios, o que simplemente no lo registre dos veces?

Answer (score 0):

Una solución sencilla a tu problema seria añadir un `bool` que se ponga en `true` una vez has guardado, y comprobar antes de guardar si ese `bool` esta en `true` o en `false`.

Cuando guardas lo pones a `true`, y cuando lees alguna información lo vuelves a poner en `false` quedaría algo así:

```
bool bGuardado = false;

foreach(/*Recorres las lineas*/)
{
    if (/*Lo que sea*/)
    {
        //Lees registros
        bGuardado = false;
    }
    else if (data[0] == "" && !bGuardado)
    {
        listinformation.Add(information);
        info.DATA = list.ToArray();                 
        string result = client.SaveInformation(information);
        bGuardado = true;
        list.Clear();
    }
}
```